# An expression which has $10$ different meanings by using some brackets appropriately

Tags: notation

My friend taught me the followings without his memory of the answer:

He said that it is known that there exists an numerical expression which satisfies the following two conditions :

**Condition 1** : The expression is represented only by "$x, y, 0, 1, +, -, \times, \div$".(each can be used multiple times.)

**Condition 2** : The expression can represent each of 
$$x+y, x-y, -x+y, -x-y, x\times y, -x\times y, x\div y, -x\div y, y\div x, -y\div x$$
if we use some brackets appropriately.

Suppose that $xy$ does **not** mean $x\times y$, which means that multiplication always needs "$\times$".

I've been trying to find the answer, but I'm facing difficulty. Can anyone help?

**Example** : By the way, $-0-x+y$ can represent each of $x+y, x-y, -x+y, -x-y$ if we use some brackets appropriately : 
$$-(0-x)+y=x+y, -(0-x+y)=x-y,$$$$ (-0-x)+y=-x+y, -0-(x+y)=-x-y.$$

Comment: Does $-(0-x(+y))=x \times y$? or $-(0-x)(+y)$?

Comment: @Henry: No. Also, suppose that a dot doesn't mean multiplication.

Comment: @Henry: Yes. I meant that neither $xy$ nor $x\cdot y$ mean $x\times y$.

Comment: But $-(A) = (-1)\times A$? That seems inconsistent.

Comment: @JonathanY.: Yes, I agree with you. My question is something like a number game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0 \times 1 + f(x,y)$$ can be written  as $$(0 \times 1) + f(x,y) = f(x,y)$$ or as  $$0 \times (1 + f(x,y))  = 0$$  so just string a sum of a large number of these together for all the possible $f(x,y)$ and switch on the ones you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Your ieda is very nice. But in my opinion, the interesting point of this question seems to be to find a specific example.

Comment: $ 0 \times 1 + x+y+ 0 \times 1 + x-y+ 0 \times 1  -x+y+ 0 \times 1  -x-y+ 0 \times 1 + x\times y+ 0 \times 1  -x\times y+ 0 \times 1 + x\div y+ 0 \times 1  -x\div y+ 0 \times 1 + y\div x+ 0 \times 1  -y\div x$

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Now you solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the following example :

$$-0+1\div1\times x-0\div 1\times 0+y$$

I think this is an example. You'll know that if you observe it.